# KeyListener- wish to input only number, but it let me input a letter

Tags: java, swing

I use this code to restrict the input only for numbers, but if the first key I press is a letter, the code let me enter that letter, only one time, then when I erase it I cannot input anymore letters, what is wrong with the code? I want to imput only numbers.

```
amount.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char c = e.getKeyChar();
        if (!(Character.isDigit(c)))
                e.consume();
        }

});
```

I added the two closing parentheses, still the same results, here is a 
[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKW5nRhMpAY)

Comment: Or a JFormattedTextField or a JSPinner. The [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/componentlist.html) has more information on these components.

Comment: hi, thanks for your coments, I know there are other options to do this, but I want to understand why this happens.

Comment: Works flawlessly here. Except that I had to add two closing parentheses. Other than that, working great. Can you make sure this is the faulty code?

Comment: I added the two parentheses, but it doesnt work for me, I post a small video showing the problem

Comment: Stop using `KeyListener`'s on text components! This is not appropriate!  Use `DocumentFilter` if your MUST do it yourself or `JSpinner` or `JFormattedTextField` which have been designed to do this job

Comment: *"but I want to understand why this happens."* - Because there are more things going on within the API then you are taking into account. There is no guarantee in which order your `KeyListener` will be notified and the key may have already been processed by the fields `KeyListener` and the `Document` updated.  It's also possible that other `KeyListener`s are ignoring the `isConsumed` property (you are). Text handling is a complex subject and the API has well defined mechanisms for handling the functionality you are trying to implement, you should use those to avoid this kind of weridness

Comment: Thanks for the explanation MadProgramer, recomendation: you should get out more :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try{
        Double.parseDouble(c);

        //Code here for TRUE case (Is Number)

}catch(NumberFormatException e1){

        //Code here for FALSE case (Is NOT Number)
}
```